# Emacs not loading init file when run as sudo

Tags: emacs

Emacs loads my `.emacs.d/init.el` startup file just fine when run as a regular user, but refuses to load it when run as `sudo emacs file.type`.  I have tried changing the owner of `.emacs.d` to `root` with no success.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a little of topic, but you could use Emacs as a normal user, and tramp to open file as root:

```
C-xC-f /sudo::/path/to/file
```

will ask you for your sudo password, and open the file as root.

Answer (score 3):

When you run as `sudo` add `-s` to preserve your environment.  It's not maintaining your environment, thus your `HOME` directory is lost.  [Emacs looks in](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) `~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, or ~/.emacs.d/init.el`, so if you lose HOME, you lose the pathing to your startup files.

Answer (score 2):

sudo -s didn't work for me.
Here is the work-around I used.

Load emacs as a normal user (so your settings take effect)

- Type `M-x customize-themes`
- Use the link to migrate your settings to a theme.
- Give your theme a name. (I unclicked the Remove saved theme settings from Custom save file.  Don't know if that affected it)
- Click save theme and note where the theme is saved.
- Exit emacs and copy your theme file to your default emacs theme folder
  (e.g. ./usr/share/emacs/24.4/etc/themes/)
- Now, open emac with sudo.
- Type `M-x customize-themes` again and you should see your newly created theme as selectable.
- Click Save Theme Settings and your sudo session will now use your custom theme in the future.

I wish there was a more elegant way of fixing this but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

jmq is right. In alternative tricky solution. If you are the only one allowed to be sudoer or to login as root, you can add a symlink in `/root/` to your `.emacs.d` directory. For example:

```
ls -l /root/.emacs
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 May  5 11:14 /root/.emacs -> /home/<user>/.emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

jmq has the right idea, the issue is because emacs looks in ~/ directories to find your .emacs file and your installed scripts.

His suggestion of `sudo -s`, if it works, is the simplest, but there's a good chance it won't work.  The problem is really a matter of how your `sudoers` is setup.  The `sudoers` is likely setup to reset your environment, which means it doesn't preserve the HOME directory for your user when it runs the sudo command.  The possible options are presented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91384/how-is-sudo-set-to-not-change-home-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-disable-this-behavior/91572#91572?newreg=8fbbf9777edf477a831ee3e6aebc204c) as the top rated response, and using `-s` can't work around most of the `sudoers` settings that will screw it up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily run emacs with the init file of your choice. For example, the following command

```
sudo emacs --load ~/.emacsroot -nw filename.ex
```

Loads emacs

- as super user -> `sudo`
- with `.emacsroot` init file located in the home directory -> `--load ~/.emacsroot`
- in console mode -> `-nw`
- opening `filename.ex` file

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
sudo emacs /etc/host.conf --directory=/path/to/.emacs.d/
```

Simplified by putting this in .bashrc:

```
function semacs { sudo emacs --directory=/path/to/.emacs.d/ $*; }
```

...so all I enter on the command line is:

```
semacs /etc/host.conf
```